# OS X / Chrome - Tunnel all traffic over HTTP Proxy?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, proxy, http-tunneling

I have written a proxy server listening on port 80 that can bypass the firewall by accessing blocked websites. It can be accessed this way: http://proxy-server/?url=http://blockedwebsite.com

How can I automate this, by forwarding all requests to http://blockedwebsite.com to http://proxy-server/?url=http://blockedwebsite.com without actually showing proxy-server in the URL?

I'm looking for a solution that works with OS X (all traffic) and Google Chrome (http / https only).

Thanks!